# How to check the objects passed through rest parameter are null or undefined?

Tags: javascript

`function extend(...args)`, if I run the function and pass a null object in this

`function extend({})`, how to check if this is null or undefined.

Input: `const first = { x: 2, y: 3};`
`const second = { a: 70, x: 4, z: 5 };` 
`const third = { x: 0, y: 9, q: 10 };` 
`const firstSecondThird = extend(first, second, third);`

Expected Output: `{ x: 2, y: 3, a: 70, z: 5, q: 10 }` 
I must also check that for each entry in `...args`, that it is an object and not undefined; if any are undefined, it must throw an error. I must also check that there are at least 2 arguments.

Comment: Now check the solution and tell me what's not working.

Comment: since you didnt reverse the objects, they are replaced by later params, so doesnt provide the expected output... errors thrown should be based on firstSecondThird and not on incoming args

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can check `length` of `Object.keys` to check `{}`. As `Boolean({})` is `true`.
- Use `includes()` to check whether `args` contain `null` or `undefined`
- Use `some()` and `typeof` to check if all the elements of array are `object`.
- You what you don't want you properties to be overwritten if its occurs twice. Then you can you `reverse()`

```js
function extend(...args){
  if(args.length < 2) throw ("Length is less than 2");
  if(!args.some(arg => typeof arg !== "object" || Object.keys(arg).length >=2 )) throw ("Arguments contain something other than object")
  if(args.includes(undefined) || args.includes(null)) throw ("Arguments contain null or undefined");
  else return Object.assign(...args.reverse()) 
   
}
const first = { x: 2, y: 3}; 
const second = { a: 70, x: 4, z: 5 };  
const third = { x: 0, y: 9, q: 10 };  
const firstSecondThird = extend(first, second, third);
console.log(firstSecondThird)


console.log(extend({}));
console.log(extend(1,2,3, undefined));
console.log(extend(1,2,3, null));
console.log(extend([]));
```

The above all if statements can be combined as one statement.

Comment: My function uses the method `Object.assign(...args)` to create a new target object using the values in the objects passed. The problem is, everytime I am executing the function, while running the code to check for null values it gives me a TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object. Any possible solutions ?

Comment: @Vedant Soni try using `Object.assign(args)`. And please show your function.

Comment: @VSoni you want to remove `null` and `undefined` from `args`?

Comment: My function composes a new object from all the entries of the objects passed without overwriting properties from earlier entries. If I use`Object.assign(args)` the function doesn't works in the way it should.

Comment: @VSoni please give your input and expected output in the original post. You question is bit short.

Comment: Input: `const first = { x: 2, y: 3};
const second = { a: 70, x: 4, z: 5 };
const third = { x: 0, y: 9, q: 10 }; const firstSecondThird = extend(first, second, third);` Expected Output: `{ x: 2, y: 3, a: 70, z: 5, q: 10 }`. I must also check that for each entry in `...args`, that it is an object and not undefined; if any are undefined, it must throw an error. I must also check that there are at least 2 arguments. Any Solutions? @MaheerAli

Answer (score -1):

you can implement this for your expected output..

```js
const first = { x: 2, y: 3 }; 
const second = { a: 70, x: 4, z: 5 };  
const third = { x: 0, y: 9, q: 10 };
const fourth = undefined;

const firstSecondThird = extend(first, second, third, fourth);

function extend (...args) {
    let result = Object.assign({}, ...args.reverse()); 
    if (result.length < 2) throw ("Length is less than 2");
    if (args.includes(undefined) || args.includes(null)) throw ("args contains undefined")
    return result;
}

console.log(firstSecondThird)
```

```js
const first = { x: 2, y: 3 }; 
const second = { a: 70, x: 4, z: 5 };  
const third = { x: 0, y: 9, q: 10 };

const firstSecondThird = extend(first, second, third);

function extend (...args) {
    let result = Object.assign({}, ...args.reverse()); 
    if (result.length < 2) throw ("Length is less than 2");
    if (args.includes(undefined) || args.includes(null)) throw ("args contains undefined")
    return result;
}

console.log(firstSecondThird)
```

Comment: Buddy your code is not throwing any error as OP said "_I must also check that for each entry in ...args, that it is an object and not undefined; if any are undefined, it must throw an error._"

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of the accepted answer.